Authorize.Net Entrust to DigiCert SSL Certificate Migration with SDK
Authorize.Net has stated they are migrating from Entrust to DigiCert certificates. They provided very little information about this. After contacting them, they were unable to provide any further clarification. We are unsure what changes, if any, are required from us due to this change.
https://support.authorize.net/knowledgebase/Knowledgearticle/?code=KA-05545
We use the Authorize.Net SDK (https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet) for authorizing payments. We only authenticate with Authorize.Net using a Login and Key, and we do not have a certificate for this.
What changes, if any, are required from us to accommodate the certificate changes?
We attempted contacting Authorize.Net, who did not provide any useful information. We went through the Authorize.Net API and did not find any information on whether the SDK requires these new certificates.

Your host or client machine was configured to the previous cert issued by Entrust. Now the Authorize.net changing its certs to a new issuer Digicert. Follow the help links provided and download the certificate and install on your host or client machine. Otherwise your application will not be able to recognize the new cert and fails to communicate with Authorize.ent api endpoints as soon as they switch cert on their end.
